# c# - what is best persistence approach/tool/library for a Directed Graph

Tags: c#, graph, directed-graph

What is best persistence approach/tool/library for a Directed Graph in C#.  That is assuming I have a class model for a directed graph (e.g. Nodes & Relationships, or Vertex's and Edge's if you like), what would you recommend regarding persisting to a SQL Database?  (or if you wish a 2nd question would be where I don't specify a SQL database as a requirement)

For example I was thinking I would simply go with a Relationships table and a Nodes table.

Comment: most popular approach I guess, or for me simple design and easy to maintain

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the tools available in C#, but your question seems to be mostly one about storage rather than C#.

How you store a DAG will no doubt depend on the use cases you have in mind.  You can represent a DAG in two tables in a relational database, for example, where one table holds information about the nodes (A, B, C, etc.) and another holds information about the edges between the nodes (A -> B, A -> C, etc.).

A graph database such as Neo4j might also be a good way to go.

Your mileage will vary when it comes to things like horizontal scaling and concurrent access, depending on the approach you adopt.  You may want to keep a denormalized representation around for speeding up some kinds of queries, but such a strategy involves tradeoffs you'll want to understand before going with it.

Answer (score 0):

A Nodes table and a Relationships (link) table seems the most natural to me since that's generally (always?) how you implement many-to-many relationships in a relational database, and a directed graph is basically a many-to-many relationship mapping for nodes (right?).  I suppose you *could* store it in an XML field, or some binary value, but that really ignores the fact that you have a database.

If you **didn't** have a database, and were writing directly to some type of file, I would probably still use a similar mechanism of uniquely identifying each node with a key and separately defining how the key values are related.

This all assumes that your directed graph is many-to-many and not strictly one-to-many.  If it were strictly one-to-many, without loops, I might use XML if writing to a file (utilizing the fact that child elements in the XML are related to their parent), or foreign keys if writing to a database (which would work well even if there were loops).

Comment: -1, A relational db is not optimized to handle this kind of data structure - and it is misleading to recommend it.  Re: SQL, SQLXML could easily support any of the standard Graph-XML schemas, which can be queried via XPath/XQuery - which doesn't 'ignore the fact' of a database, but leverages its features.  However, RDBMS is not the way to go.  While this is possible to implement using a relational model, the performance on large data sets will be significantly slower than an implementation with a graph db (e.g. neo4js, like @EricWalker suggested)

Comment: @smartcaveman, The question kind of asked specifically about working with a SQL database, and since my experience is primarily limited to SQL databases and the task can be accomplished with SQL, this answer seemed appropriate to me. My answer was provided long before Eric's so it's not surprising that better answers exist. But if you are working with SQL, I still think this is *a* reasonable answer. Also, when I say that using XML ignores the fact that you have a database, my point is that SQL's ability to query XML data isn't better than the ability to query XML from a file when used this way